# stuck to calculate the percentage

Tags: c#

I have four text box A ,B,C and D.

Textbox A and B is user input field for example txtA = 250 ; txtB =300;

based on formula ((B-A/A)*100) i found value for C (%). After find the txtC (%20)value i have to find txtD.

To find out txtD, i have set of pre defined value to find txtD.

for example

```
if the % <10 then txtD=1
10-20 then txtD=2
20-30 then txtD=3 like wise until 100 %
```

. I am not sure whats the best approach to achieve this.  i am just wondering create  percentage table and handle or using switch statement is the best approach.

Comment: first please post some `code` and a question - second it seems you are asking for opinions which is not what you want to do here (there is a code-review and a programmers site where this belongs IMO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why isn't it possible using simple if..else blocks?
`Switch..Case` is not appropriate when comparing  range of values..

```
int D = (0.2 * C);

If (D < 10) {
  txtD=2
}
elseif (D > 10 && D < 20){
  txtD=3
}
elseif (D > 20 && D < 30){
  txtD=4
}
..
```

Comment: Thanks,its is possible but i am wondering which one is effective compare to back end or the front end